# Managing iPhone app provisioning profiles

Tags: iphone, build-process, provisioning

I just created an iPhone app and am having friends try it out, but it seems like there's a lot of stuff that needs 'management' in order to have efficient development/test cycles. There are also a bunch of things which are only on my machine (the Keychain and my test cert that I use to create the app/provisioning profiles) which other developers on the team cannot use.

- How are folks managing the different kinds of iPhone certs and provisioning profiles?
- Any suggested best practices on how to efficiently build/test/provision app builds in ways that anyone from the team can do it?
- What exactly needs to be backed up in case I want to re-build my mac or use another mac to do developments/builds?
- Which of these artifacts are needed for actual deployment to the app store? Do I need to re-create certs, profiles etc or do I just re-use the ones I've created for development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work with several clients, each with there own certificates and app store accounts.  I create a separate keychain with all the certificates and keys for each.  You can pass these keychains around or back them up as needed.

For years, I had to set the default keychain each time I switched projects, but that is finally fixed.

As for the provisioning profiles themselves, there is not much to do.  You can always go download a fresh one and these days they expire pretty quickly anyway.

@paull opinion: totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a single file containing all of your certificates and provisioning profiles, which is the best way of managing your own bits.

For an app store build, you need a personal certificate, an app I'd (which can be generic if you aren't using push or the store), and a provisioning profile for the app store - only the latter is specific to your app store build.

Opinion: Apple's provisioning management is utter balls.

Comment: This single file you talk of includes the private cert from my Keychain? How do I create this? And is this for backup purposes only, or also to help others build/manage provisioning?

Comment: It does include your cert, and is intended to allow you to move between machines more easily.  There's an export/import menu option somewhere in Xcode, check the Organizer window first.  Not good for helping others, but you can always download the provisioning profiles, which should be all they need, from the Dev center.